# Talkback: "Double tap" (ACTION_CLICK) is missed on Samsung

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, talkback, accessibility

I'm trying to add a custom ACTION_CLICK text. This what I'm doing:

```
ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(mButton, new AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host, AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat info) {
                super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info);

                AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.AccessibilityActionCompat customClick =
                        new AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.AccessibilityActionCompat(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.AccessibilityActionCompat.ACTION_CLICK.getId(), "do something");
                info.addAction(customClick);

                String text = "123 Text";
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
                    info.setText(text);
                }
            }
        });
```

On Nexus it works well, after clicking, the following is announced:
"123 Text button, double tap to do something".

But on Samsung Galaxy s6 I hear the following:
"123 Text button".

My custom action has no effect :(
Is it configured somewhere in the device settings or maybe I need to specify something else? Where Voice Assistant on Samsung "hides" this "double tap"?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.samsung.com/in/support/skp/faq/1100638

Comment: @KingofMasses The question is not to how enable the TalkBack. I know how to enable it, but why it works different on Nexus and Samsung. Maybe there're some additional configurations on Samsung that should be enabled or I should configure it different in my application.

Comment: @YuliyaTarasenko : Could you mention Android OS version?

Comment: @Palak The version is 7.0 (Samsung) and 7.1.2 (Nexus)

Comment: It's sort of interesting, maybe different vendor have different implementation for the talkback service.